# Exercise 7, Chapter 5, Sheaves in Geometry and Logic

Tags: category-theory, group-actions, topos-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $G$ be a group object in a topos $E$.Prove directly that $U: E^G \rightarrow E$ has a right adjoint.

I know that $U: Sets^G\rightarrow Sets$ has a right adjoint but I don't know how to generalize it for an arbitrary topos...

Comment: You say right adjoint in one place and left in the other. Anyway, can you mimic the description of the adjoint over Set?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake because $U: Sets^G\rightarrow Sets$  has both right and left adjoints. I don't understand the differences in proofs.... I don't know why I can't just put $E$ instead of $Sets$?

Comment: Well, I guess this is exactly what the exercise is about. You need to go through the proofs over Set and verify that they work over an arbitrary topos.

Comment: (... and figure out how to make adjustments in places when the proofs you have in mind don't carry over word for word)

Comment: Hey Sajad, firstly sorry for this distrupting comment, I will delete it soon; from your name I guessed that you're from Iran, like me. I'm very interested in reading _sheaves in geometry and logic_. I was wondering if I can contact you to ask a little bit of questions about that; I don't see any contact info on your profile, so I would be very glad if you contact me through my email which is available on my profile. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your email. @Kooranifar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

The idea is the same as for Sets. Define the right adjoint by $Y \mapsto Y^G$ with the $G-$action defined as the transpose of $G \times G \times Y^G \xrightarrow{m \times 1} G \times Y^G \xrightarrow{ev} Y.$

To see that this is an action, we need to show that the diagram commutes:

\begin{CD}
G \times G \times Y^G @>{1\times\mu}>> G \times Y^G \\
@V{m \times 1}VV @V{\mu}VV \\
G \times Y^G @>{\mu}>> Y^G.
\end{CD}

Let's transpose it, using the definition of $\mu$: the equality $ev \circ( m \times 1) = ev \circ(1 \times \mu).$ Then we will use the fact that multiplications commute with each other, and transpose back. Transposing and using the this equality gives

\begin{CD}
G \times G \times G \times Y^G @>{1\times 1\times\mu}>>  G \times G \times Y^G @>{m \times 1}>> G \times Y^G \\
@V{1 \times m \times 1}VV @. @V{ev}VV \\
G \times G \times Y^G @>{m \times 1}>> G \times Y^G @>{ev}>> Y.
\end{CD}

Since $(m \times 1) \circ(1 \times m\times1) = (m\times1) \circ (m \times 1\times1) $ and also $(m \times 1) \circ (1\times 1\times\mu) = (1\times\mu) \circ (m \times 1\times1),$ this is the same as the diagram

\begin{CD}
G \times G \times G \times Y^G @>{m \times 1\times 1}>>  G \times G \times Y^G @>{m \times 1}>> G \times Y^G \\
@. @V{1 \times \mu}VV @V{ev}VV \\
@.G \times Y^G @>{ev}>> Y.
\end{CD}

But this commutes by the definition of $\mu$.

To show adjointness, suppose we are given $f: UA \to Y$. Define $\bar{f}$ by $G \times A \xrightarrow{\mu} A \xrightarrow{f} Y.$ The transpose of this, $A \xrightarrow{g} Y^G,$ is to be the transpose along the adjunction we are constructing. E.g. to see that it's equivariant, consider

\begin{CD}
G \times A@>>>   G \times Y^G  \\
@VVV @VVV \\
A @>>> Y^G.
\end{CD} Transposing this gives
\begin{CD}
G \times G \times A@>{1 \times 1 \times g}>>   G \times G \times Y^G @>{m \times 1}>> G \times Y^G\\
@V{1\times \mu}VV @. @V{ev}VV \\
G \times A @>{\mu}>> A @>{f}>> Y.
\end{CD}
Quite like before, we now have
$$ev \circ (m \times 1) \circ (1 \times 1 \times g) =  ev \circ (1 \times g) \circ (m \times 1) = \bar{f} \circ (m \times 1) = f \circ \mu \circ (m \times 1) = f \circ \mu \circ (1 \times \mu),$$
so this commutes.

To go back along the adjunction we construct, we evaluate, like in Sets, at $e:$ $A \simeq 1 \times A \xrightarrow{e \times 1} G \times A \xrightarrow{1 \times g} G \times Y^G \xrightarrow{ev} Y$.

The proof that these are reciprocal is done in a similar fashion.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to draw diagrams. We can just use the usual element proofs when we use the notion of a generalized element in category. Put differently, the Yoneda Lemma allows us to transport many statements, also this adjunction here, from $\mathbf{Set}$ to any category (which has the structure we are talking about).